# Traveling with lots of luggage at Brussels, Midi Railway Station (ZYR)

Tags: trains, luggage, brussels

I am flying with Air France from Montreal to Brussels and then take the Thalys to Cologne, which is my final destination. Air France booked me on a train from Paris to Brussels, so I will already be at the train station in Brussels. I have three large bags and backpack as carry-on. So, I probably won't be able to carry those bags.

Do they provide luggage carts or something similar at the train station in Brussels? Will Air France forward my luggage to Brussels or will I have to haul it onto the train?

Edit 1: Air France does not forward the luggage to Brussels. It has to be picked up at CDG and then hauled on the train (I am at CDG at the moment, will update)

Edit 2: I successfully switched the trains in Brussels. It was a bit of a headache. Supposedly there are carts available, but I couldn't find any on the platform. All the TGV/Thalys/Eurostar platforms are very close together, so I was able to get to my train with a little help from people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pass through the Brussels-Midi station quite regularly. I cannot say for sure, but it is a large station, including the Eurostar terminal, and so I imagine that it is possible to get hold of cart if you ask someone when you get to the station (if you can speak French this would help).

I would advise checking exactly how much time you have at Brussels-Midi. If you have 45 minutes or more then that should be plenty of time to find a member of station staff/a cart to help get your luggage to the relevant platform. If you have less time then it could be tricky. You could probably ask the ticket collector on the train to Brussels and they could advise you what to do when you arrive.

[The Man in Seat 61](http://seat61.com) may have some helpful information on [his luggage page](http://www.seat61.com/Europe-train-travel.htm#Luggage). I would be surprised if Air France will forward your luggage for you, but I guess you should ask them to check.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I actually have more than 2 hours in Brussels. So I'll hope I will be fine. I will update my post when I get home! I am leaving Montreal tonight.

Comment: As the luggage rules prevent most people from traveling with many pieces of luggage, it is not amazing that there is little help. Also the luggage cards are anoying when there are many people crowding the platforms, so most people want them gone rather than readily available.